# Estimating the value of pi using the Monte Carlo method and plotting the error graph

Tags: python, statistics, montecarlo

I was trying to calculate the value of pi using the Monte Carlo method, taking a square and a quarter circle with a radius equal to the side length of the square. However, as I was calculating the percent error, my graph was not correct.

I had defined a function that generates random points in a square and counts the points that are in the quarter circle defined by the side length of a square.

```
def count(N):
  x = []
  y = []
  for i in range(N):
    x.append(random.uniform(0,1))
  for i in range(N):
    y.append(random.uniform(0,1))

  count_in = 0
  x_in = []
  y_in = []
  x_out = []
  y_out = []
  for i in range(N):
    if math.sqrt((x[i]**2 + y[i]**2)) <= 1:
      x_in.append(x[i])
      y_in.append(y[i])
      count_in += 1
    else:
      x_out.append(x[i])
      y_out.append(y[i])
  return x_in, y_in, x_out, y_out, count_in
```

the lists are for plotting the points, pls don't mind them.

When it came to plotting the percentage error vs the number of points generated, I wrote the code

```
errors = []
numbers = []
for i in range(250):
  N = 8*i
  x1,y1,x2,y2,count_in,count_tot = count(N)
  if count_tot != 0:
    error = abs(math.pi - 4*count_in/count_tot)/math.pi*100
    errors.append(error)
    numbers.append(N)
```

The result should have been as the image below:
[correct graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrk7L.png)

Although it was decreasing, the result was too jiggly and not coming that close to 0 as the number of points generated was increasing.

[my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s890e.png)

I was told that my code was creating a different scenario each time, instead of adding 1 more point to the recently calculated N points, and this was the problem. Surely this was the case since when I abided by the suggestions I obtained the graph
[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HoZC.png)
But why is that the case?

Comment: Adding points incrementally means the change is bounded between two consecutive estimates. However, by running a new trial every time the difference between those can be much bigger which translates into bigger noise into the graph, but yes both should converge to zero.